# google people api is returning empty list of contacts

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I am using googleapis in my node.js project. At first I was using raw api which was working, but when I switched to googleapis package, the list of people.connections.list is returning me an empty object, and I have some contact saved in my account, which was showing up when I was using raw apis.

Here is the code that I wrote from the documentation.

```
const getContacts = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
const peopleServices = google.people({
      version: "v1",
    });

    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: "./gmail-api-nodejs-399211-9be0ced71d07.json",
      scopes: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.language.read",
        "profile"
      ],
    });

    const authClient = await auth.getClient();
    google.options({ auth: authClient });

    const resourceName = "people/me";

    const result = await peopleServices.people.connections.list({
      resourceName: resourceName,
      personFields: "names,emailAddresses",
    });
    console.log(result.data);
    return res.json(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the script of `At first I was using raw api which was working`? By the way, in your showing script, the service account is used. Is this related to your current issue?